# Interesting in obtaining a SQL query to find most "bounty-deserving" questions

Tags: discussion, bounty

What would a SQL query be (for Data Explorer), that reveals questions that are deserving of answers (i.e quality answers that would yield bounty-rewards) ? I did trawl through the "Unanswered questions" page, but many of these are theoretical-type questions from 5 years prior; which nobody really can answer.

But there must be some good questions, from within a month or two; where the asker maybe doesn't have the reputation to give out their own bounty.

I feel that bounties may be used for rewarding good questions, that perhaps don't have any good answers yet either (so, the query maybe can check the upvote/downvotes of existing answers ).  It's not *only* that a question has no answers, but that even those *with* answers have good answers.

May we please have such query (or page that highlights these questions) ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

The following SEDE query ([SEDE link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/379839)) returns the top 100 unanswered, non-merged questions, ordered by their score divided by the square root of their age; this will favor high-score and new questions. You could tweak the exact weighting of those two terms to get different orderings.

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 q.Id as [Post Link], q.Score,
  DATEDIFF(DAY, q.CreationDate, GETDATE()) AS Age,
  q.Score/(SQRT(DATEDIFF(DAY, q.CreationDate, GETDATE())+1)) AS Immediacy FROM Posts q
LEFT OUTER JOIN Posts a on q.Id=a.ParentId
WHERE q.PostTypeId=1 AND a.Id IS NULL  -- Unanswered question
AND NOT q.Id IN (SELECT ph.PostId FROM PostHistory ph WHERE ph.PostHistoryTypeId=37) -- Not merged
ORDER BY q.Score/(SQRT(DATEDIFF(DAY, q.CreationDate, GETDATE())+1)) DESC
```

The first few questions returned look promising:

- [changing property masksToBounds in transform-only layer, will have no effect-> Xcode 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32456727/3093387): Score 91, age 45 days, unanswered.
- [Haskell threads heap overflow despite only 22Mb total memory usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31641464/3093387): Score 77, age 89 days, unanswered.

One possible modification would be to limit to questions in tags where you are active, since you'll be more likely to know how to answer those questions.

Comment: Thanks for the link -- I didn't realize Data Explorer was a significant term, or that this resource existed.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the "Newest" or "Active" tab of the Unanswered questions page, if "Relevance" or "Votes" happen to be the default. These tabs would avoid showing 5-year-old stale questions on the first few pages.

See also the help for advanced search options on the [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) page. For example:

```
score:10 hasaccepted:no lastactive:3m..1m created:5m closed:no wiki:no
```

The above would filter for questions without an accepted answer, created recently (5 months or sooner), that are "somewhat stale" (no activity in 1-3 months) but had activity (for a while ~2 months and at least 10 votes), that also are not closed or community wiki questions.

Comment: You could also add `intags:mine` that adds your favorite tags to the search. Also the `+` removes the score parameter from the search. If you just do `score:10` it finds questions with score >= 10.